# counting(summing) total visits within a year from the first visit date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count(sum) the number of visits from first visit date to next 1 year, for example in case of A there are total 3 visits within 1 year and in case of B there are total 4 visits within a year from first visit date.

or

I want to extract the rows for each patient who has visits within first year and not intrested for rows where visits are more than a year.

| Patient_ID | Visit_code | Visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | F | 2021-02-01 |
| A | FT | 2021-05-08 |
| A | FX | 2021-10-15 |
| A | FT | 2022-08-09 |
| B | FX | 2020-04-05 |
| B | FT | 2020-08-07 |
| B | FT | 2021-03-04 |
| B | FT | 2021-04-04 |
| B | FX | 2023-01-02 |

I want to count(sum) the number of visits from first visit date to next 1 year, for example in case of A there are total 3 visits within 1 year and in case of B there are total 4 visits within a year from first visit date.

or

I want to extract the rows for each patient who has visits within first year and not intrested for rows where visits are more than a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this a simple one is to find the first visit per patient and then count how many times the patient visited between the first visit and the following year something like this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Patient_ID VARCHAR(10),
    Visit_code VARCHAR(10),
    Visit_date DATE
)
INSERT INTO MyTable(Patient_ID, Visit_code, Visit_date)
VALUES
('A', 'F',  '2021-02-01'),
('A', 'FT', '2021-05-08'),
('A', 'FX', '2021-10-15'),
('A', 'FT', '2022-08-09'),
('B', 'FX', '2020-04-05'),
('B', 'FT', '2020-08-07'),
('B', 'FT', '2021-03-04'),
('B', 'FT', '2021-04-04'),
('B', 'FX', '2023-01-02')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Patient_ID, MIN(Visit_date) FirstVisit, MIN(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, Visit_date)) MaxVisitRange
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Patient_ID
)
SELECT CTE.Patient_ID, COUNT(1) NumberOfVisits
FROM MyTable 
INNER JOIN CTE 
    ON CTE.Patient_ID = MyTable.Patient_ID
        AND MyTable.Visit_date BETWEEN FirstVisit AND MaxVisitRange
GROUP BY CTE.Patient_ID
```

Comment: Hello @Luis LL , thanks for the script , it works as i thought.

Comment: with pleasure, will you please upvote as well for future reference for others?

Comment: could you pls guide me how to upvote , i could not find it, thanks in advance

Comment: Just click the upward triangle at the left of the response